# Angular2: How to display details of an element on another page?

Tags: angular, master-detail, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I've got a list of orders on a first page, and I would like to display the details of one of the orders on another page, to be able to update it, and save it when going back to the home page. Here is my code:

The app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {OrderDetailsComponent} from './order-details/order-details.component';
import {MockComponent} from './mock/mock.component';
import {NavbarComponent} from "./navbar/navbar.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'main',
    template:`
        <navbar>Loading navbar...</navbar>
        <div class="container">
            <router-outlet>Loading body...</router-outlet>
        </div>
    `,
    directives: [HomeComponent, OrderDetailsComponent, MockComponent, NavbarComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/',             name: 'Home',          component: HomeComponent,        useAsDefault: true},
    {path:'/order/:id',    name: 'OrderDetails',  component: OrderDetailsComponent},
    {path:'/mock',         name: 'Mock',          component: MockComponent}
])

export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {}
}
```

The home.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';

import {AppServices} from '../services/app.services';
import {Order} from '../objects/order';
import {OrderDetailsComponent} from "../order-details/order-details.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './app/home/home.html',
  providers: [AppServices],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public orders: Order[];

  onSelect(order: Order) {
    this._router.navigate( ['OrderDetails', { id: order.id }] );
  }

  constructor( private _appServices: AppServices, private _router: Router, routeParams: RouteParams) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOrders();
  }

  getOrders() {
    this._appServices.getOrders()
        .subscribe(res => this.orders = res);
  };
}
```

The order-details.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Order} from '../objects/order';
import {AppServices} from '../services/app.services';

@Component({
    selector: 'order-details',
    templateUrl: './app/order-details/order-details.html',
    inputs: ['order'],
    providers: [AppServices]
})

export class OrderDetailsComponent {

    public order: Order;

    constructor(private _appServices: AppServices) {
    }
    updateOrder(order: Order) {
        this._appServices.updateOrder(order);
    }
    onSubmit() {
        this.updateOrder(this.order);
    };

}
```

The order-details.html :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #orderForm="ngForm">

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="type">Type :</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="order.type">
            <option *ngFor="#type of types" [value]="type.typeEnum">{{type.text}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="wishProducts">Wish products :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="order.wishProducts">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="budget">Budget : </label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="order.budget">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="dateDelivery">Delivery date: </label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="order.dateDelivery">
    </div>
...
```

Comment: you either can send object of values via RouteParams and get those values back into another page where you want or you also can send values by clicking somewhere there are no. of methods available or can use some global service kind of file to exchange data between components.

Comment: I see you tried to do that by using a master - detail view navigation using the router, where one view displays a summary and then another displays a detail. This seems the right approach, so the question is not clear. Did something went wrong, what didn't work? did you get any error messages, run into difficulties?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I tried to use a global service to share my order object, but I've got a "EXCEPTION: TypeError: l_order0 is undefined in [order.id in OrderDetailsComponent@1:36]". Do you know where it could come from? When I am on the order detail page, I've just got the form, without the information of the selected order in it.

Comment: OK I have found where the error was coming from: I had imported the global service in home.component and order-details.component instead of app.component. Thanks again to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean another component instead of another page.

When one component is part of the view of the other element or when both have a common parent element you can use template binding.

In all other cases you can use a global service to share data.